# document.getElementsByClassName().innerHTML always returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I must have made a mistake somewhere so the `document.getElementsByClassName().innerHTML` is always returning **undefined**.

First i generate the `<li>` via javascript :

```
$('#list').append('<li class="box"><img class="picture" src="images/HotPromo/tagPhoto1.png"/><p class="name"><b>Name</b></p><p class="address">Address</p><p class="hidden"></p></li>');
```

Note that in the most right i have a `<p>` element with `hidden` class. I use this to get the **id** which i dont want to show to my users.

And this is the jQuery to generate the data on those `<li>` :

```
$(".box").each(function () {
    var name, address, picture, id = "";
    if (i < result.length) {
        name = result[i].name;
        address = result[i].address;
        picture = result[i].boxpicture;
        id = result[i].mallid;
    }

    $(this).find(".name").html(name);
    $(this).find(".address").html(address);
    $(this).find(".picture").attr("src", picture);
    $(this).find(".hidden").html(id);
    i++;
});
```

I have tried to check the data, and its working fine.

Now, lets say i want to alert the hidden **id** `<p>` when user clicks one of those `<li class="box">` that i generated above:

```
$(".box").click(function () {
    alert(document.getElementsByClassName('hidden').innerHTML);
});
```

However this alert always returning "**undifined**".

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why are you using plain JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: @putvande err..sorry thats because im a beginner...i will try to use just jQuery :D

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a nodeList, not an element!

So it should be :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0].innerHTML
```

and as you probably have more `.hidden` elements, and only want the one inside the current `.box` (which would be `this` in the event handler)

```
this.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0].innerHTML
```

but why not jQuery

```
$(".box").click(function(){
        alert( $('.hidden', this).html() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :D Yes, i will try to use just jQuery :D

so if i just want to use jQuery, i also need to change "$(this).find(".name").html(name);" to  "$('.name', this).html();" right?