# javascript dynamic content not affected when ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to javascript, am using PHP variable for created link dynamically as given below

```
$addlink = '<button class="blueBtn btnSmall" id="current'.$product_id.'"    onClick=addcart('.@$product_id.',"add")><span class="allitem"
<font color="#A2F3AB">Added</font></span></button>';
```

This my php variable created by dynamically like below.
Added 
Added 
Added

I want to change the content of all variable“ added” as“ add” by just one click,Am using ajax function for changing that text as given below..

```
function clearcart(msg) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('cartreturn').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementsByClassName('allitem').innerHTML = "Add";

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/addcart.php?msg=" + msg, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

But first link text only affected.. other is not affected how I can solve this problem

Comment: -1 for bad formatting of your question.

Comment: @RahulDesai 99% of questions are badly formatted -- it sometimes seems like I spend more time fixing indentation than answering. :)

Comment: Please don't use `<font>` html tag. It's deprecated and you can achieve the same by styling "allitem" class in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`. You have to iterate over all the elements:

```
var allItems = getElementsByClassName('allitem');
for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
    allItems[i].innerHTML = 'Add';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896746/document-getelementsbyclassname-innerhtml-always-returns-undefined).

You can't do `document.getElementsByClassName('allitem').innerHTML`.

You can do `document.getElementsByClassName('allitem')[0].innerHTML = "Add"`

Do you have several elements with the class "allitem"? If you don't, then maybe you should use an id, instead of a class, and then call `document.getElementById('allitem').innerHTML = "Add";`